# asp.net mvc bootstrap align button verically in the boostrap alert section

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am adding a button denoted as x inside an bootstrap alert section. It is possible to have more than 1 line of message but the x button is at the top right. I need the x button to be vertically aligned in the middle. I tried "style="vertical-align: middle" but it is not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align: middle">×</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                @{
                    string[] errorlist = errorMessage.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    foreach (string error in errorlist)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                        {
                            <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: #FF0004;"></i> @error</li>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/vsakd/8/) example which does this with divs.

```
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
       I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
    </div>
</div>

.parentbox {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:solid;

    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    font: 16px/1 Arial, sans-serif;  /* reset the font property */

    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```